# What are the differences between jxl vs apache poi vs jexcel?

Tags: apache-poi, xls, xlsx, jxl, jexcelapi

what are the relevant differences between this libs ? also can tell me anyone about the license of this products ?

i need to generate large files .xlsx files. Until now i used jxl lib in for .xls with a a formated header using jxl.write.WritableCellFormat.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself yet on these products?

Comment: You should check this question for the second part of your question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17313008/1469523

Comment: Probably check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980717/what-is-the-better-api-to-reading-excel-sheets-in-java-jxl-or-apache-poi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluation from Apache POI and JExcel Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865961/evaluation-from-apache-poi-and-jexcel-api)

Comment: Here is the a more in-depth of both JXL and POI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980717/what-is-the-better-api-to-reading-excel-sheets-in-java-jxl-or-apache-poi/14986986#14986986

Answer (score 6):

1) JXL is now JExcel.

2) You can get all list of differences between JExcel and Apache POI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980717/what-is-the-better-api-to-reading-excel-sheets-in-java-jxl-or-apache-poi)

3) Both are free.

4)You should use Apache POI because JExcel does not support .xlsx format.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between JXL and POI is that Java JXL does not support the Excel 2007+ ".xlsx" format; it only supports ".xls" format. 
Apache POI supports both with a common design.